# Problem with network when external HDD to be mounted at boot is absent

Tags: networking, boot, fstab

I have a Raspberry PI (RPI), running Arch Linux, and I have an NTFS external HDD (with its own power source), which is mounted at boot via fstab: 
/dev/xxxx /boot
/dev/sda1 /mnt/usbhdd/ ntfs-3g ...etc. # <-- external HDD

When the external HDD is plugged to the RPI, it boots fine: I can ssh into the RPI and I can access the HDD. However, when the external HDD is NOT plugged in (say, it is needed elsewhere), I cannot ssh into the RPI after booting and my router doesn't see the RPI either. But then, when the external HDD is plugged back in at this point, after some time I am able to ssh in again.

Is this because: if the external HDD is not plugged in, fstab hangs and rest of the boot scripts are not executed? If so, is there a way around it?

Comment: It appears the answer may be to add "nobootwait" option in fstab: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53377/do-not-halt-the-boot-if-an-fstab-mounting-fails